# Is there a way to handle undefined functions being called in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, undefined

If I have a function like the following:

```
function catchUndefinedFunctionCall( name, arguments )
{
    alert( name + ' is not defined' );
}
```

and I do something silly like

```
foo( 'bar' );
```

when foo isn't defined, is there some way I can have my catch function called, with name being 'foo' and arguments being an array containing 'bar'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is in Mozilla Javascript 1.5 anyway (it's nonstandard).

Check this out:

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function () {
        alert('foo!');
    }
    , __noSuchMethod__: function (id, args) {
        alert('Oh no! '+id+' is not here to take care of your parameter/s ('+args+')');
    } 
}
myObj.foo();
myObj.bar('baz', 'bork'); // => Oh no! bar is not here to take care of your parameter/s (baz,bork)
```

Pretty cool. Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod

Comment: This is very cool and nearly exactly what I was looking for - is there an equivalent that works in IE 6+?

Comment: As of december 2015, this is an obsolete function  that shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @Loïc what should be used then?

Answer (score 6):

```
try {
 foo();
}
catch(e) {
   callUndefinedFunctionCatcher(e.arguments);
}
```

**UPDATED**

passing `e.arguments` to your function will give you what you tried to pass originally.

Comment: `arguments` is not a property of the `Error` object, it is a property of functions.  In your example `e` is an error object and so `e.arguments` will be undefined.

Comment: I think it is just that kind of checking the catch-all strategy people want to get away from.

Comment: I just ran the following in chrome:

try {
   bar('foo');
}
catch(e){
   alert(e.arguments);
   for(x in e) {
     alert(x)
   }
}

it alerts 'foo' and then alerts 'arguments' as a property of e. Am I crazy? Or just still wrong?

Comment: doing try/catch in JS is not always a good idea, specially if there are async functions inside the block. Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677783/is-it-possible-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-in-a-javascript-async-callback

Answer (score 0):

```
someFunctionThatMayBeUndefinedIAmNotSure ? someFunctionThatMayBeUndefinedIAmNotSure() : throw new Error("Undefined function call");
```