# Error-handling try & catch + callback?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to catch exceptions thrown in a JavaScript async callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677783/is-it-possible-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-in-a-javascript-async-callback)

I am pulling orders from a database and then requesting, I want to be able to break the `forEach` and I can do that with a `try` and `catch` but I think that the callback isn't working

```
try{
    orders.find().forEach(function(order){
        request({
            "method":"get",
            "json":true
        },function (error, response, data){
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("Order id "+order.id);
            }else{
                throw "limit";
            }
        });
    });
}catch(err){
    if(err == "limit"){
        console.log("error occured");
    }
}
```

This is what I'm getting

```
    /Users/thomas/Desktop/forerunner/retrieveTransactions.js:120
                throw "limit";
                ^
    limit
```

I just want:

```
    error occured
```

Comment: @pimvdb not the same because of the `forEach`.

Comment: The answer is more or less the same: not possible. It actually makes sense because the ajax is finished later than the `forEach` ends.

Comment: If you want to stop iteration, just declare a flag before you call `orders.find()` and set it when you encounter an error.  Any subsequent handlers can query it and return. If the interface supports it, you can also use `some()`, which stops processing as soon as the handler returns `true`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add try-catch inside the callback function, something like:

```
orders.find().forEach(function(order){
    request({
        "method":"get",
        "json":truetry{
    },function (error, response, data){
        try{
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("Order id "+order.id);
            }else{
              throw "limit";
            }
        }catch(err){
            if(err == "limit"){
                console.log("error occured");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't break the `forEach` and is also a bit overkill. Just put the code in the `else` block.

Comment: It actually works now