# using try catch on error generated by asynchronous callback function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to catch an error caused by an async javascript callback function,

```
try{
  setTimeout(()=>{ 
    throw err 
    console.log("after throw") 
  }, 1000)
}catch(e){
  console.log("caught");
}
```

But as many of you may know catch block is never executed, so **what exactly is happening here**?

I know I can achieve similar thing using promises and async/await,

```
async foo(){
  try{
    await setTimeoutPromise(1000);
  }catch(e){
    alert("caught");
  }
}
```

Comment: or [Error-handling try & catch + callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203224/error-handling-try-catch-callback)

Comment: It's not quite the same. The scope of this question is more about the reason, not the workaround.

Comment: but the answers do include the reason, duplicate does not mean mirror images.

Comment: [Don't throw exceptions in asynchronous callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25144936/1048572). Throw them in promise callbacks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use setTimeout, the callback gets pushed into the event loop (moved out of the JS Engine and into the realm of the runtime/browser) and your `foo` function exits immedeatly.

After the timeout AND once the stack is empty, the event loop will put the callback onto the stack and run it. That's why the try/catch and the callback are independent of each other. That's also why `setTimeout(1000)` does not mean *in a second* but *not earlier than and somewhat close to one second*.

See [What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: I should had probably given a better introspection before posting this.. :/

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things.

The first code won't catch the error, since it happens asynchronously, and `try...catch` will only catch synchronously thrown exceptions.

The second code **will** catch the error, because `await` 'synchronize' the code (makes it look and work like it would've been synchronous), and the error [**thrown only by `await`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Examples): if you haven't been used it, you would get only a rejected promise ([You can't really throw anything from an async function!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value))

To make the first code working, move the `try...catch` inside the callback:

```
setTimeout(()=>{ 
  try{
    throw err
  }catch(e){
    console.log('catched')
  }
  console.log("after throw") 
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that `async/await` "synchronize" the code. It remains asynchronous, just easier to understand and deal with.

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, I know, that's why I quoted the word 'synchronize'. I haven't found the accurate way to express what I would like to say... Now I've rephrased it, so it might be clearer.