# Why redefining the variable not throwing the error in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have below piece of code in my nodejs. Here I have defined `screenshot` as `const` and then redefine it as you can see below. Here the issue is my code was neither throwing any error nor being executed further after the console `console.log('opopopopopoopoooooopop')`. After sometime I figured out the reason is "I have taken `screenshot variable as const".

```
const handler = async(request, reply) => {
  try {
    const screenshotPath = ''
    console.log(request.payload, 'ddddddddddddddddddd')
    let folderName = `./public/applications/${applicationId}`
    let filepath = `${folderName}/${className}.png`
    mkdirp(folderName, async(err) => {
      await imageUpload(file, className, filepath)
      console.log('oooooooooooooooooooo')
      if (err) {
        return reply({ success: false, message: err.message, data: null })
      }
      console.log('opopopopopoopoooooopop')
      screenshotPath = filepath
      console.log(Event)
      const screen = await Event.findOne({ })
      console.log(screen, 'popopopopopoopopooop')
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err })
    return reply({ success: false, message: err.message, data: null })
  }
}
```

But the problem is why my code was not throwing the error here. Can someone please help me to get understand this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to catch exceptions thrown in a JavaScript async callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677783/is-it-possible-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-in-a-javascript-async-callback)

Comment: did you try to add try-catch block in inner async function?

Comment: @JamesDeSouza no... can single try catch cannot do this?

Comment: apparently not! when you run async method, it's work like another thread. not something to catch with.

Comment: @JamesDeSouza So is there any way to handle with single `catch` block?

Answer (score 2):

An error within an `async` function causes the returned `Promise` to reject.

...but if nothing is using that `Promise`:

```js
const handler = async () => {
  try {
    const screenshotPath = '';
    const callback = async () => {
      screenshotPath = 'redefined'; 
    }
    const promise = callback();  // <= promise will reject...
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('in catch');  // ...but this never runs
  }
  console.log('finished');
}

handler();
```

...then nothing happens.

This is called an **unhandled promise rejection**.

---

On the other hand, if the same `Promise` is `await`-ed, then the catch will get called:

```js
const handler = async () => {
  try {
    const screenshotPath = '';
    const callback = async () => {
      screenshotPath = 'redefined'; 
    }
    await callback();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('in catch');  // this runs!
  }
  console.log('finished');
}

handler();
```

---

So since the error happens in an `async` callback, the `Promise` it returns will reject, but since nothing is using that rejected `Promise` nothing happens.

---

### Solution

It looks like your `mkdirp` function follows...

> the common error-first callback style, i.e. taking an `(err, value) => ...` callback as the last argument

...so you could use Node's [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create a version of `mkdirp` that returns a `Promise`:

```js
const util = require('util');
const mkdirpPromisified = util.promisify(mkdirp);

const handler = async(request, reply) => {
  try {
    let screenshotPath = ''
    let folderName = `./public/applications/${applicationId}`
    let filepath = `${folderName}/${className}.png`
    await mkdirpPromisified(folderName)
    await imageUpload(file, className, filepath)
    if (err) {
      return reply({ success: false, message: err.message, data: null })
    }
    screenshotPath = filepath
    const screen = await Event.findOne({ })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err })
    return reply({ success: false, message: err.message, data: null })
  }
}
```