# Can you catch an exception thrown by a function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie at JavaScript. I am passing a function as a parameter to another function and trying to catch the exception being thrown. Here is the function I'm passing:

```
let foo = async function() {
   throw 'error on the outside'
}
util.retryWrapper(foo);
```

and here is the wrapper function:

```
function retrySleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function retryWrapper(testCallback) {
    console.log('inside the retry wrapper');
    console.log('function: ');
    console.log(testCallback);

    let sleepTime = 5000;
    let retryFlag = true;
    let maxTimeoutReached = false;

    do {
        try {
            console.log('just before applying the function');
            testCallback();
            console.log('just after applying the function');
            retryFlag = false;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('inisde the catch');
            if (sleepTime > 30000) {
                console.log('sleeptime > 30000');
                retryFlag = false;
                maxTimeoutReached = true;
            } else {
                console.log('increasing the sleeptime');
                sleepTime *= 2;
                await retrySleep(sleepTime);
            }
        }
    } while (retryFlag);

    if (maxTimeoutReached === true) {
        console.log('max timeout was reached');
        throw 'Error: Test exceeded max timeout.';
    }

    console.log('end of the retry wrapper');
}
```

I expect that when `testCallback();` is called, the exception will be thrown and then it will go to the catch block and begin the log statements there etc. but it never goes into the catch when executed:

```
inside the retry wrapper
function:
[AsyncFunction: foo]
just before applying the function
just after applying the function
end of the retry wrapper
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677783/is-it-possible-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-in-a-javascript-async-callback) is similar, but since I have access to the 'callback' in this case why isn't the exception being caught?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Uwe for pointing out I was missing an `await`. As a follow up question, what I'm doing is passing test logic to the wrapper. Since I'm awaiting that now, Mocha (the test framework I'm using), incorrectly says the test has passed even though it hasn't:

```
it('should update a contact', async function () {
   let foo = async function() {
      throw 'error on the outside'
   }
   util.retryWrapper(foo);
 });
```

and the output:

```
inside the retry wrapper
function:
[AsyncFunction: foo]
just before applying the function
inisde the catch
increasing the sleeptime
      √ should update a contact
      1) should look up a contact by id
just before applying the function
inisde the catch
increasing the sleeptime
just before applying the function
inisde the catch
increasing the sleeptime
just before applying the function
inisde the catch
sleeptime > 30000
max timeout was reached
```

The `should update a contact` test should not pass however, as it only is throwing an exception. Is there a way I could stop the wrapper from exiting and going back to the outer 'tests' until its time increasing logic has gone to its end and in this case at least the test correctly displays a failure?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `testCallback()` with `await`?

Comment: You're right! Tt's printing out the statements in the catch now. Thanks so much.

Comment: As a follow up, is there a way I could wait until the wrapper is done completely before exiting back to the outside caller function? Now it will enter the catch and 'increase the sleeptime' but since I'm using await the app continues on outside of the wrapper. I don't want the app to move on until the wrapper is completely done with it logic (of increasing the timeout until > 30000)

Comment: For more context I am running tests using Mocha and because the test logic in the callback is being awaited it now things the test has passed even though it should not: `inside the retry wrapper
function:
[AsyncFunction: foo]
just before applying the function
inisde the catch
increasing the sleeptime
      √ should update a contact
      1) should look up a contact by id
just before applying the function
inisde the catch
increasing the sleeptime`

Comment: So here's the deal, your question lacks focus, but I commend you for throwing test functions around to test results, this is how we learn, and IMO, its the best way to learn. With that said, callbacks are useally Asynchronous, (There are exceptions to this rule, but thats a talk for a later time) that means when V8/Spider Monkey or what ever JS inturpreter your useing, gets  to the callback that you wrote into the  the try and catch block, the JS Engine executes the code within it. When it gets to...

Comment: When it gets to your callback, it sends it to the event loop because it is asynchronous. The engine basicly says, "_Ill comeback and execute this later, when single and only thread is not busy_". The JavaScript engine continues to execute code, it finishes the try and catch block, and continues on to other functions that are qued inside of the call-stack. Finally it finishes, and nothing is level in the stack, now the JS-Engine says, "okay I got time to execute that callback now", so it executes the callback, but theres a problem, something is very wrong, something is missing...

Comment: The try & catch block no longer exists, because its not stored in memory, and the engine already ran through the part of the script where it uses your instructions to implement the block. The engine does know this though, so it continues with business as usual, it calls and executes the callback, and what do you know, an error occurs! JavaScript gets mad now, and says "How dare you no handle this exception", then JavaScript leaves, and your stuck with program that just exited, and an unhelpful, angry JavaScript Message.

Comment: My suggestion to you, is learn how promises work, so you can learn how, `async` & `await` work. Then you will learn things like how to properly handle errors for the different asynchronous syntax's. Just, FYI, It is possible to handle asynchronous code with a try/catch block, but its sorta fictitious, its called syntactic sugar. Really, under the hood ASYNC & AWAIT  are just promises. Their is only one difference that I have noticed, and that is the callstack will sometimes show an asynchronous function call as being asynchronous when used with the ASYNC keyword.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234393/discussion-between-9thwave-and-jaydev).